# Extract Audio from Video AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

```
func extractAudioFromVideo(videoUrl:NSURL, audioPath:String){
    //2
    var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoUrl, options: nil)
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(NSArray(object: "tracks") as [AnyObject], completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        var audioTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] as! AVAssetTrack

        var audioComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        var audioCompositionTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack!

        audioCompositionTrack = audioComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, ofTrack: audioTrack, atTime: CMTimeMake(0, 1), error: nil)

        var exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: audioComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
        var toFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath)

        exportSession.outputURL = toFileUrl
        exportSession.outputFileType = "com.apple.m4a-audio"

        exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
            if exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {
                println("Succes")
            }else{
                println("not working")
            }
        })

    })

}
```

I am using above code to get audio from video, but it is printing "not working"

my audioPath is:

`var outStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cheeseburger", ofType: "m4a")`

Please help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I have re-written the answer for **Swift 4.0** since several API changes broke the previous one.

```
import AVFoundation

extension AVAsset {
    // Provide a URL for where you wish to write
    // the audio file if successful
    func writeAudioTrack(to url: URL,
                         success: @escaping () -> (),
                         failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
        do {
            let asset = try audioAsset()
            asset.write(to: url, success: success, failure: failure)
        } catch {
            failure(error)
        }
    }

    private func write(to url: URL,
                       success: @escaping () -> (),
                       failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
        // Create an export session that will output an
        // audio track (M4A file)
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self,
                                                       presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else {
                                                        // This is just a generic error
                                                        let error = NSError(domain: "domain",
                                                                            code: 0,
                                                                            userInfo: nil)
                                                        failure(error)

                                                        return
        }

        exportSession.outputFileType = .m4a
        exportSession.outputURL = url

        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            switch exportSession.status {
            case .completed:
                success()
            case .unknown, .waiting, .exporting, .failed, .cancelled:
                let error = NSError(domain: "domain", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }

    private func audioAsset() throws -> AVAsset {
        // Create a new container to hold the audio track
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        // Create an array of audio tracks in the given asset
        // Typically, there is only one
        let audioTracks = tracks(withMediaType: .audio)

        // Iterate through the audio tracks while
        // Adding them to a new AVAsset
        for track in audioTracks {
            let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio,
                                                               preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
            do {
                // Add the current audio track at the beginning of
                // the asset for the duration of the source AVAsset
                try compositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(track.timeRange,
                                                      of: track,
                                                      at: track.timeRange.start)
            } catch {
                throw error
            }
        }

        return composition
    }
}
```

Then, you call the extension, and rely on the different closures to process successes and failures. The error handling in this example is extremely primitive, so you will want to improve that when implementing it.

```
asset.writeAudioTrack(to: url, success: {
    print("Success")
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (domain error 0.), However, it does that to some files only, otherwise it works.

Comment: Shows this : Error Domain=domain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: @sharadchauhan That is the generic error that I create to indicate the creation of the exportSession failed. This likely indicates that there is something wrong with the asset you are using. Check to make sure that it has an audio track for staters.

Comment: @CodeBender It has. But also it has green screen. Can that be the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

From my project (**Swift 4.1**)

```
import AVFoundation
extension AVAsset {

    func writeAudioTrackToURL(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> ()) {
        do {
            let audioAsset = try self.audioAsset()
            audioAsset.writeToURL(url, completion: completion)
        } catch (let error as NSError){
            completion(false, error)
        }
    }

    func writeToURL(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> ()) {

        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else {
            completion(false, nil)
            return
        }

        exportSession.outputFileType = .m4a
        exportSession.outputURL      = url

        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            switch exportSession.status {
            case .completed:
                completion(true, nil)
            case .unknown, .waiting, .exporting, .failed, .cancelled:
                completion(false, nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func audioAsset() throws -> AVAsset {

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()
        let audioTracks = tracks(withMediaType: .audio)

        for track in audioTracks {

            let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
            try compositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(track.timeRange, of: track, at: track.timeRange.start)
            compositionTrack?.preferredTransform = track.preferredTransform
        }
        return composition
    }
}
```

Use like this

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "m4v")!
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)

    let pathWhereToSave = "<#path#>"
    asset.writeAudioTrackToURL(URL(fileURLWithPath: pathWhereToSave)) { (success, error) -> () in
        if !success {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```